# Urllib/JSON request from text file

Tags: python, json, urllib2

I am trying to send data from a text file  to a server looking for a match to the sent data in order to get that matched data returned back to me that I store in an existing text file.  If I send a list of names to the server within the script, I am fine.  I however want to repeat the request and insert a text file as the names to be matched and returned.  Here is my text so far:

```
import json
import urllib2

values = 'E:\names.txt'
url = 'https://myurl.com/get?name=values&key=##########'


response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
with open('E:\data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(response, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4,ensure_ascii=False);
```

This code just send back a one line file showing nothing has matched.  I am assuming that it is just looking at the values as the name instead of the data in the values text file.

Update Trial 1:  I updated my code as per suggested below to include the urllib.urlencode suggestion.  Here is my updated code:

```
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

file = 'E:\names.txt'
url = 'https://myurl.com/get'
values = {'name' : file,
          'key' : '##########'}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(req))
with open('E:\data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  json.dump(response, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4,ensure_ascii=False);
```

fixed traceback errors by editing url.  However it is just passing "e:\names.txt" as name in the JSON request.  So it seems my issue now is just trying to send the data in the names.txt file to the tuple 'names' properly.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when sending parameters to server, they're encoded -- see [urllib.urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode)

Comment: I tried using at top file = 'E:\names.txt'
url = 'https://myurl.com'
values = {'name' : 'file',
          'key' : '###########'}  and it sent me back a whole ton of errors using this resource:https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html